# applying a function to all columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is part of a data frame:

```
df2:
**headache**                                             **Sweating**                        
C0018681 / Headache / Sign or Symptom        C0038990 / Sweating / Finding
C0233408 / Disorientated in time / Finding   C0037195 / Sinus headache / Finding
```

I am going to remove spaces in all columns using the following function:

```
def codeCleaning (df, column):
    df[column].replace('\s*/\s*', '/', regex=True, inplace = True)
    df[column] = df[column].str.strip() 
    df[column] =df[column].str.lower()
    return df
```

I created a list of the columns header as follow

```
column=list(df2.columns.values)
```

Then I tried to apply the function to all columns, but it did not work. This is my 
 code:

```
df2 = codeCleaning (df2,column )
```

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str.lower, map(str.strip, x.split('/')))))

                                 headache                         Sweating
0       c0018681/headache/sign or symptom        c0038990/sweating/finding
1  c0233408/disorientated in time/finding  c0037195/sinus headache/finding
```

---

To address mixed types, you can cast as `str`

```
df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str.lower, map(str.strip, x.split('/')))))
```

Comment: thank you. as the function shows, I also need to set all the values to lower case and strip the spaces at the begging and end of the cells. Would you please let me know how I can do it ?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: I am sorry. the code return this error in my dataset: AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index headache').

Comment: You must have `float` in your column `headache`  Which isn't reflected in your sample data.